# How could we know that monetDB is using Index?

Tags: indexing, explain, monetdb

I have loaded 150 million records into MonetDB. All data inserted into a single table. The table does not have any constraint(ex. `UNIQUE`, ..). I have not created any index myself. The original source CSV file is about 7.2 GB and after importing database is about 8GB. I ran a `COUNT(*)` with `WHERE`, it returned in 12 seconds. according to documentation:

> The index statements in the SQL standard are recognized, but their
>   implementation is different from competitive products. MonetDB/SQL
>   interprets these statements as an advice and often freely neglects it,
>   relying on its own decision to create and maintain indexes for fast
>   access.

Now How can know that MonetDB has created index itself? I used `EXPLAIN` but I didn't understand the output:
This is the actual query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vbvdata WHERE vbvdata_speed > 80 AND vbvdata_lane_id = 2;
```

and this is the `EXPLAIN` output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mal                                                                            |
+================================================================================+
| function user.s11_1{autoCommit=true}(A0:bte,A1:bte):void;                      |
|     X_4 := sql.mvc();                                                          |
|     X_46:bat[:oid,:bte]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_speed",0);   |
|     X_38:bat[:oid,:bte]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_speed",2);   |
|     X_48 := algebra.kdifference(X_46,X_38);                                    |
|     X_49 := algebra.kunion(X_48,X_38);                                         |
|     X_32:bat[:oid,:bte]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_speed",1);   |
|     X_50 := algebra.kunion(X_49,X_32);                                         |
|     X_18:bat[:oid,:oid]  := sql.bind_dbat(X_4,"sys","vbvdata",1);              |
|     X_19 := bat.reverse(X_18);                                                 |
|     X_51 := algebra.kdifference(X_50,X_19);                                    |
|     X_25:bat[:oid,:bte]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_lane_id",0); |
|     X_27 := algebra.uselect(X_25,A1);                                          |
|     X_23:bat[:oid,:bte]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_lane_id",2); |
|     X_28 := algebra.kdifference(X_27,X_23);                                    |
|     X_24 := algebra.uselect(X_23,A1);                                          |
|     X_29 := algebra.kunion(X_28,X_24);                                         |
|     X_21:bat[:oid,:bte]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_lane_id",1); |
|     X_22 := algebra.uselect(X_21,A1);                                          |
|     X_30 := algebra.kunion(X_29,X_22);                                         |
|     X_31 := algebra.kdifference(X_30,X_19);                                    |
|     X_52 := algebra.semijoin(X_51,X_31);                                       |
|     X_53 := algebra.thetauselect(X_52,A0,">");                                 |
|     X_55 := algebra.kdifference(X_53,X_38);                                    |
|     X_41 := algebra.semijoin(X_38,X_31);                                       |
|     X_42 := algebra.thetauselect(X_41,A0,">");                                 |
|     X_56 := algebra.kunion(X_55,X_42);                                         |
|     X_35 := algebra.semijoin(X_32,X_31);                                       |
|     X_36 := algebra.thetauselect(X_35,A0,">");                                 |
|     X_57 := algebra.kunion(X_56,X_36);                                         |
|     X_58 := algebra.kdifference(X_57,X_19);                                    |
|     X_59 := algebra.markT(X_58,0@0:oid);                                       |
|     X_60 := bat.reverse(X_59);                                                 |
|     X_12:bat[:oid,:lng]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_id",0);      |
|     X_10:bat[:oid,:lng]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_id",2);      |
|     X_14 := algebra.kdifference(X_12,X_10);                                    |
|     X_15 := algebra.kunion(X_14,X_10);                                         |
|     X_6:bat[:oid,:lng]  := sql.bind(X_4,"sys","vbvdata","vbvdata_id",1);       |
|     X_16 := algebra.kunion(X_15,X_6);                                          |
|     X_61 := algebra.leftjoin(X_60,X_16);                                       |
|     X_62 := aggr.count(X_61);                                                  |
|     sql.exportValue(1,"sys.vbvdata","L1":str,"wrd",64,0,6,X_62,"");            |
| end s11_1;                                                                     |
| # optimizer.mitosis()                                                          |
| # optimizer.dataflow()                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can not know when MonetDB creates/uses an index. This is determined dynamically based on each operator invocation.